# Is there any benefit to putting application variables in Application.rb vs an initializers/file.rb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, configuration

There's a lot of suggestions on where to store your application wide variables, including a few gems that do it for you. For Rails 4 the most simple way I've found to do this is to add a variable to 'config' in either Application.rb or an initializers/file.rb like such

```
#/config/application.rb
config.new_variable = 5
```

or

```
#/config/initializers/application_variables.rb
Rails.application.config.new_variable = 5
```

I'm wondering if there's any difference in these two, maybe load times, or if the one in application gets called everytime the application is refreshed, etc...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This definitely depends on the intended usage. I would use `/config/application.rb` to only configure the actual Rails application. Not to store miscellaneous variables used in my own code. Thats just a global in disguise.

For API keys and other secret bits and bobs the answer is using environmental variables combined with initializers:

```
# /config/initializers/boozehound_client
# a fictional API client 

Boozehound.configure(
  api_key: ENV['BOOZEHOUND_API_KEY'],
  secret: ENV['BOOZEHOUND_API_SECRET']
)
```

Otherwise if you need to use a variable across controllers you could place it your `ApplicationController`.